# How to change NeuralNetwork options?

Tags: options, machine-learning, neural-networks

How can I manipulate the architecture and problems of a NeuralNetwork in `Predict` or `Classify`? For example, running the following code shows a number of properties of the generated network.

```
data = {Range[1, 100], RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 0.01], {100}] - Range[0, 0.1, 0.1/(100 - 1)]} // Transpose;
data = Rule @@@ data;
model = Predict[data, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"];
PredictorInformation[model]
```

How can I manipulate the options such as the regularization coefficients, the number of hidden layers, the number of hidden nodes, and the hidden layer activation functions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As already mentioned, options are accessed via:

```
Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "L2Regularization" -> 0.12,  "HiddenLayers" -> {4, 3, 3}}
```

To manually set the activation functions of the first and second hidden layers:

```
"HiddenLayers"-> {{4, "RectifiedLinear"}, {3, "Tanh"}, 3}
```

Currently, the following activation functions are supported:

```
{"LogisticSigmoid", "RectifiedLinear", "Tanh", "SoftRectifiedLinear", "Linear"}
```

Non-zero "L1Regularization" is not yet supported.

The usual proviso: These options are undocumented functionality whose form may change substantially in future versions.

Comment: Great, thanks. Another clarification: is it possible to specify the activation of the output layer?

Comment: Not directly. For the output layer, Classify uses softmax (to get class probabilities) and Predict uses linear. But Classify and Predict give you the outputs, so you can take this and apply a custom activation function. Or do you want to change the loss function used for training?

Comment: So, it is indeed, as I assumed, a specific "HiddenLayers" format that is needed, but I only tried to specify functions instead of names as strings  :-(

Comment: Setting `"L2Regularization"` seems to hang  the kernel in 10.4, has the option been changed?

Answer (score 14):

At least

```
Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "L2Regularization" -> 0.01,  "HiddenLayers" -> {4, 3, 3}}
```

seems to work. `"L1Regularization"` doesn't seem to be settable. Haven't found out about activation functions yet.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Update

More options can be found using

```
Options@MachineLearning`PackageScope`NeuralNetworkPredictor
```

> {"BinaryEncoder" -> "Identity", "ClassNumber" -> Automatic, 
>        "CrossValidation" -> Automatic, "DataSize" -> All, 
>        "EarlyStopping" -> Automatic, "HiddenLayers" -> Automatic, 
>        "L2Regularization" -> Automatic, "LearningTask" -> "Predict", 
>        MaxIterations -> Automatic, NominalVariables -> Automatic, 
>        PerformanceGoal -> Automatic, "PrintCost" -> False, 
>        "OptimizationMethod" -> Automatic, 
>        "WeightInitializationMethod" -> Automatic}

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start. I would really like to be able to set the activation functions though, so if you can figure that out, this will be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Italianice There really doesn't seem to be a named option to specify activation functions, but I have reasons to believe that it should be possible to do that using a particular format for the "HiddenLayers" option specification. I couldn't find out what would do the trick though.

Comment: Does running `Options[model]` provide any clues? The output contains `"NeuronTypes" -> {"Tanh", "Tanh", "Linear"}`, but it is inside some nested association structure that I don't yet understand.

Comment: Do you know how can I change "CrossValidation"?

Comment: @Miguel You might want to look into ``MachineLearning`PackageScope`ParseCrossValidationOptions ``. It seems to list its options, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However I can't get it work either...