# Setting MaxIterations for neural network function `Predict`?

Tags: neural-networks

The neural network implementation of `Predict` seems to support a number of undocumented options as shown in a previous question: [How to change NeuralNetwork options?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64785/how-to-change-neuralnetwork-options).

Has anyone had succes trying to set the values of `MaxIterations` and `EarlyStopping`? What is the proper syntax for setting these options?

Answer (score 2):

```
c = Predict[{1 -> 1.3, 2 -> 2.4, 3 -> 6.4, 4 -> 10.1}, 
        Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "HiddenLayers" -> {4, 3, 3}, 
        "L1Regularization" -> 0.5, "DropOut" -> True, 
        "MaxIterations" -> 1000, "ValidationSet" -> True}]
```

But when I add `"EarlyStopping" -> False` it throws error.