# How to add hidden layers and plot these?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a question regarding neural network graphs.

In R there is the following code where a user can add hidden layers with different number of nodes:

```
n <- neuralnet(medv ~ crim+zn+indus+chas+nox+rm+age+dis+rad+tax+ptratio+b+lstat,
           data = data,
           hidden = c(12,7),
           linear.output = F,
           lifesign = 'full',
           rep=1)
```

At the above table `c(12,7)` means that there will be 2 hidden layers with 12 nodes for the first and 7 for the second.
And we plot it, it gives the following plot:
[image: Plot of a neural net]

Is there anything similar for Mathematica? I have searched and I have found some info although it seems it is not working.

At [How to change NeuralNetwork options?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64785/how-to-change-neuralnetwork-options)
there is a code that says at the point to define the Method we have to apply

```
data = {Range[1, 100], RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 0.01], {100}] - Range[0, 0.1, 0.1/(100     - 1)]} // Transpose;    
data = Rule @@@ data;    
model = Predict[data, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"];    
PredictorInformation[model]
```

And then we apply the following:
 `Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "L2Regularization" -> 0.12,  "HiddenLayers" -> {4, 3, 3}}`

In my case when I run the above code, the following message appears:
[image: After the run of the code]

And the following as a result:
[image]

Is there something like analytical notes that explain all that?

Answer (score 3):

By default, Predict with "NeuralNetwork" as a method creates a neural network with 2 hidden layers of width 50 (nodes)

```
data=Rule@@@({Range[1,100],RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,0.01],{100}]-Range[0,0.1,0.1/(100-1)]}//Transpose);
model = Predict[data, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"];
Information[model, "MethodParameters"]
```

Gives <|"NetworkDepth" -> 2, MaxTrainingRounds -> 300|>, which implies there are 2 hidden layers.

To extract the NetChain object in the NetGraph object created by Predict, we can use:

```
NetExtract[(First@model)["Model", "Network"], {"1"}]
```

[image: NetChain]

Which shows us that there are two hidden layers with 50 nodes each, with SELU activation functions.

We can change the amount of hidden layers with the option NetworkDepth:

```
model2 = Predict[data, Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "NetworkDepth" -> 1}]
```

[image: NetChain model 2]

If you want to have more control over the structure of the neural network, you can use NetChain instead to define it:

[image: NetChain model 3]

Which has 3 hidden layers, of width 4, 3 and 3 respectively, and SELU activation function.

Then, you can train this model with the data:

```
model3trained = NetTrain[model3, data]
```

And then use it for predictions:

[image: Prediction]

Then you can generate plots of the network.

[image: MXNet Style Graph]

[image: Mathematica Full Summary Graph]